# Sql select query with varchar (max) is taking too much time

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a sql query that goes like this:

```
with history as (select columnA,columnB,columnC,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by columnA ORDER BY columnD desc) as rownum from TableA )
select m.columnA,m.columnB,m.columnC from history as m where m.rownum=1
```

This is taking about 5 minutes to execute.
After trying out different things, i found out if i dont include columnC, which is an nvarchar (max), i get result in 2 seconds. But i need this columnC in my results.

I want to make this query run faster. I only have a read-only connection string to the db and don't have permissions to modify the table.

I tried putting the data into a paged table as someone suggested in stackoverflow and that didn't help.
I also tried limiting the characters i receive in the paged table for columnC, that didnt work either:

```
Create Table #PagedTable (
 columnA nvarchar(255),
 columnB nvarchar(255),
 columnC nvarchar(1000),
 rownum int
);

with history as (select columnA,columnB,columnC,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by columnA ORDER BY columnD desc) as rownum from TableA )

Insert into
        #PagedTable
select m.columnA,m.columnB,m.columnC from history as m where m.rownum=1

Select * from #PagedTable
```

How can i modify this query to make it run faster?
This is running against sql azure server v12 version
As you can see in the query, what i am trying to do is number the rows partitioning by columnA and getting the first row in each category

EDIT: Adding more information:
Index is only on columnA. The table has about 10000 rows, result has 2359 rows.

Comment: So, do your `SELECT` or `INSERT` from `CTE`?

Comment: How many rows in the table? How many rows in the results? What indexes are on the table?

Comment: Try to select only the unique keys of TableA in the CTE and join the rest of the columns you need at the end after you reduced result set down to what you need (only the first row of each partition).

Comment: Index is only on columnA. The table has about 10000 rows, result has 2359 rows. I select from CTE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How long does it take for this version to run?

```
select h.columna, h.columnb, h.columnc
from (select columna, max(columnd) as maxd
      from history h
      group by columna
     ) hh join
     history h
     on h.columna = hh.columna and h.columnd = hh.maxd;
```

This assumes that you have an index on `history(columna, columnd)`.

Comment: This is awesome! It took just 2 seconds! Instead of min(columnd) i had to put max as i wanted the value corresponding to last value of columnd. (Original query had ORDER BY columnD desc). Thanks!